# npm ERR! Missing script: "serve" npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in Vuejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Hello hope you are well!

I am working on project VUEJS after I setup the project  install vuejs, also bootstrap and run npm run serve me display this error:

npm ERR! Missing script: "serve"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-22T21_48_27_572Z-debug-0.log

Any idea How to solve it? Thanks
[image]

Comment: You need to add a "serve" script under "scripts" in `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

In order to run npm scripts that are defined inside of `package.json` you have  to be in the dictionary, where the `package.json` file is located. You tried to run the script from `crud-app-Frontend`, but your `package.json` is actually located in `crud-app`.

You have to navigate there and then run the script.

```bash
$ cd crud-app
$ npm run serve
```